# Django Json field filter throws lookup error

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.9, django-jsonfield

I am using django postgres JSONfield and the model structure is as below

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class JsonAnswer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data = JSONField(default={})
```

the data present in the Json field is as below

```
{
 "owner":{
    "name":"Bob",
    "other_pets":[
      {
       "name":"fishy"
      }
    ]
   },
 "bread":"lab"
}
```

and my filter query is like this

```
JsonAnswer.objects.filter(data__owner__name="Bob")
```

which is throwing the error

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'owner' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Please explain how to filter the json field data

Comment: probably unrelated to your error but make sure when you set default value for a JSONField, use `dict` or `dict()` instead of `{}`, because it "creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of JSONField".. see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, above, you have the correct type of `JSONField`, but the error suggests that the column is not defined as `jsonb` in the database, for whatever reason (that's what the issue was for me when I encountered a similar error).